# Simple select statement consumes server memory in SQL Server or times-out

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, memory, out-of-memory

I am running a very simple select statement that returns a single `varchar(50)` column from a large table (over 10 million rows). The table already has a pk

Example:

```
select employee_name from tblEmployees
```

In .net I use a `SqlDataReader` to read back the data

1. sometimes the query times-out
2. SQL Server memory usage rises till it consumes all server resources and is not released when `SqlDataReader` and/or connection is closed

Please is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Code:

```
    Dim M1 As String() = {"234701", "234703", "234704", "234705", "234706", "234707", "234708", "234709", "234802", "234803", "234804", "234805", "234806", "234807", "234808", "234809", "234810", "234811", "234812", "234813", "234814", "234815", "234816", "234817", "234818", "234819", "234909", "234902", "234903", "234905"}
    Dim M2 As String() = {"2347025", "2347026", "2347027", "2347028", "2347029"}
    Dim M3 As String() = {"23490", "23491"}

    Dim N1 As New Dictionary(Of Long, Byte) 'ok
    Dim N2 As New Dictionary(Of Long, Byte) 'maybe

    Function GetMobile(v As String) As Mobile
        If v.Length < 10 Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim sb = New Text.StringBuilder

        For i = 0 To v.Length - 1
            Select Case v(i)
                Case "0"c To "9"c
                    sb.Append(v(i))
            End Select
        Next

        Dim m = "234" + Right(sb.ToString, 10)

        If m.Length = 13 Then
            If M1.Contains(Left(m, 6)) OrElse M2.Contains(Left(m, 7)) Then
                Return New Mobile With {.number = CLng(m), .ok = OK.Yes}
            ElseIf Left(m, 6) = "234702" OrElse M3.Contains(Left(m, 5)) Then
                Return New Mobile With {.number = CLng(m), .ok = OK.Maybe}
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

Using dr = **ExecuteReader**("select col1 from myTable")
  While dr.Read
      If dr.IsDBNull(0) Then Continue While

      Dim m = GetMobile(CStr(dr(0)))

      If IsNothing(m) Then Continue While

      Select Case m.ok
          Case OK.Yes : N1(m.number) = 1
          Case OK.Maybe : N2(m.number) = 2
      End Select
  End While
End Using

Public Function **ExecuteReader**(sql As String) As SqlDataReader
    Dim conn = New SqlConnection(connString1)
    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe post your code, just the bit where you open your data reader?  You could also try increasing the command timeout?

Comment: what does your *reader* do? Is it possible, for example, that your reader is doing enough per-row that it is much much slower than the incoming data stream, therefore forcing sql server to create a large output-buffer for the connection? and yes: it is not uncommon for processes to hold onto memory they have obtained; internally defragmenting (compacting) and releasing memory is complex and expensive

Comment: @MarcGravell see sample code added

Comment: @RichardHansell, MarcGravell when I run the same query in SQL Management Studio, I get rows back almost immediately, even thought the query might take a litle while to complete. I can extend the command time-out to handle that. But why are rows not streamed to the SQlDatareader? that would keep memory usage very low and performance much higher... is this option possible?

Comment: @CharlesO not only is it possible: that is how it usually works; it looks like it is trying to buffer it all for some reason; I wonder - have you considered using *paging* instead of trying to fetch everything at once? maybe pages of 10,000 items?

Comment: This might be on completely the wrong track, but does that "using dr..." bit actually work, i.e. when the using block ends does it dispose of the sql connection and sql command objects as well as the data reader?  I would be tempted to move the connection and command objects inline and stick them in using blocks explicitly just to test that the behaviour doesn't change...

Comment: Try commenting out the body of the reader `WHILE` loop and check the timings.  I suspect the performance issue is in the application code.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP why would the application code cause a sql time-out? I will try commenting out the code but, I doubt that would help at all

Comment: @RichardHansell i just used this setup for convenience. I have same issues of SQL Server holding onto memory long after the connection has closed even when i have all the connection and command code within a single using statement - no different.

Comment: @MarcGravell How does SQL Management Studio do it? the same query runs with minimal memory footprint. How do we achieve that in our own code?

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP i'm basically parsing for valid Nigerian mobile numbers {"234[789][01]...."}, I could use Regex...but looking i don't  see how that would be more efficient that my current method, which does simple fixed length header lookup

Comment: @CharlesO, it is normal for SQL Server to acquire and not release all the memory it can.  This is good for performance on a dedicated server.  But if other application run on the same machine (including this one), it may be best to limit SQL Server memory and prevent thrashing.